# In American English, "was passed" or "was overtaken"?

Tags: word-choice

As far as I know, it is common in American English to say "to pass him" instead of "to overtake him".

However, is it common for a sports commentator in the USA to say

> "Тhe runner was **overtaken** at the very end of the race"

or would

> "Тhe runner was **passed** at the very end of the race"

be still more common?

Comment: I can't think of any objective way to measure which is *more* commonly used in this context.  Your answers are likely to be based on personal opinion, not any kind of third-party measurement.

Comment: @Andrew - My answers?! I didn't give any answers here. I only posted a question.

Comment: Sorry, "your answers" is short for "the answers you receive to your question".  For example, I might disagree with Jay's answer below, but there are no statistics we can point to to prove which if us is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "passed" is more common but both are routinely used and would be readily understood. Neither would strike a fluent speaker as odd.